# How to solve a error "stdout | fatal: A branch named 'deploy-old' already exists."

Tags: git, itamae

When using `git` resource I got following error:

```
INFO : Recipe: /Users/ironsand/dev/itamae_myserver/recipe.rb
ERROR :     stdout | fatal: A branch named 'deploy-old' already exists.
ERROR :     Command `cd /opt/my_project && git branch -m deploy-old` failed. (exit status: 128)
ERROR :   git[/opt/my_project] Failed.
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I login the server and delete the branch `deploy-old`.

```
ssh my_server
cd /opt/my_project
sudo git branch -d deploy-old
```

After that I could apply the recipe without error.